# Xamarin forms Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy recibiendo este error,

> Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

tras implementar lo siguiente en mi código

```js
public Comenatrios(int ID) {
  InitializeComponent();
  IdCom.Text = ID.ToString();
  IdCita = ID;
  GetComentarios(IdCita);

  //esta es la parte que implenté
  var periodTimeSpan2_ = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);

  var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
  var timer2_ = new System.Threading.Timer((e) => {
    GetComentarios(IdCita);
  }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan2_);
}

// tambien intenté con esto, pero necesito que se corra ese metodo cada 4 o 5 segundos        
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  GetComentarios(IdCita); // este metodo es un simple get a un api
});
```

O alguien sabe como puedo hacer algo similar a lo que pretendo? En el sentido de que necesito correr un método en un vista mientras esta esté activa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con un Timer:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        GetComentarios(IdCita);
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: oye y cómo puedo detenerlo???

Comment: El return true es el que se ocupa de repetir. Puedes pararlo pasando a false. Utiliza alguna variable que te ayude en esta tarea.